# PHP Array sorting algorithm

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array suppose of 30 records. For example values of array are `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30`

Now What I was it to be sorted as `1,7,13,19,25,2,8,14,20,26,3,9,15,21,27,4,10,16,22,28,5,11,17,23,29,6,12,18,24,30`

If you see the output the difference is 6 and set is of 5 numbers. I hope it will be clear now.

I have tried using `remainder` logic, but no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: An array can't have nine keys with the same value. Something must be wrong

Comment: sorry I have edited the array. It was mistake.

Comment: still question is unclear @MShahzadKhan. what do you mean by `If you see the output, every index value has different of 6 (columns), and then it start from another value and difference of 6, until all the indexes are filled.`?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I can't even see a question or anything that indicates the problem

Comment: You should add a sample input and sample output.

Comment: @MShahzadKhan  please check how to ask a good question :- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why don't you make it a multidimensional Array?

Comment: The question is still unclear. Please update it and post the input array, the expected output array and a clear explanation why that one is the expected array.

Comment: I hope it will be clear now. @AlivetoDie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question (and I guess correctly the many things you didn't care to explain), you have a list of values and want to partition it. Each partition should contain numbers from a sequence of numbers with step 6.

I wrote a helper function that generates the sequences of numbers with step 6 between a minimum and a maximum value:

```
function sequence($min, $max, $step) {
    $result = array();
    for ($i = $min; $i < $min + $step; $i ++) {
        $result = array_merge($result, range($i, $max, $step));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

If called with `2`, `9`, `3` it generates:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 8

    [3] => 3
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 9

    [6] => 4
    [7] => 7
)
```

In order to use it to sort the records mentioned in the question, call it with minimum and maximum values from the input list then intersect the result with the input list (it is possible that the input list doesn't contain all the values between minimum and maximum):

```
$input = array(3, 18, 19, 15, 16, 6, 8, 10, 20, 12, 7, 11, 17, 5, 9);
print_r(array_intersect(sequence(min($input), max($input), 6), $input));
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 15

         # 4 is not present in the input list
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 16

    [6] => 5
    [7] => 11
    [8] => 17

    [9] => 6
    [10] => 12
    [11] => 18

    [12] => 7
          # 13 is not present in the input list
    [14] => 19

    [15] => 8
          # 14 is not present in the input list
    [17] => 20
)
```

Comment: I thought all of them will be genius like you :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
$arr = array();
for ($idx = 0, $val = 1; $idx < 29; $idx++, $val += 6) {
    $arr[$idx] = $val % 29;
}
```

Sorry, but your question is way too unclear.

Comment: Very nice.  Clean

Answer (score 0):

This should produce the required array

```
<?php
$start = 1;
while( $x < 3 )
{

  for( $a = 0; $a < 5; $a++ )
  {  
    $array[] = $start + ( $a * 6 );

  }
  $start++;

  $x++;
}
var_dump( $array );

array(15) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(7)
  [2]=>
  int(13)
  [3]=>
  int(19)
  [4]=>
  int(25)
  [5]=>
  int(2)
  [6]=>
  int(8)
  [7]=>
  int(14)
  [8]=>
  int(20)
  [9]=>
  int(26)
  [10]=>
  int(3)
  [11]=>
  int(9)
  [12]=>
  int(15)
  [13]=>
  int(21)
  [14]=>
  int(27)
}
```